# Excel match text of one cell with another and remove the matching text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have an excel sheet with two columns, `"Brand Name"` and `"Title"`. I want to generate a cell that removes the `"Brand Name"` from the `"Title"`.

How can I achieve this with an `excel formula`?

I have attached a `screenshot` of the file.

[image]

Comment: Use the `SUBSTITUTE` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Basic Text Functions

- You can solve this in many ways. Here are some that use basic `Excel` functions:

**All Occurrences**

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,""))
```

**First Occurrence**

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,"",1))
```

**Concatenated Space**

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1&" ","",1)
```

**First Space (`B`-Column Only)**

```
=RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND(" ",B1))
```

**Length + 1 (For the Space):  `- (LEN(A1) + 1) = - LEN(A1) - 1`**

```
=RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-LEN(A1)-1)
```

**Length + 1 (For the Space)**

```
=REPLACE(B1,1,LEN(A1)+1,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this
Assume the column A for brand and B for Title
=A1&" "&RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND(" ",B1))